# Iterating on list with stream in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

what would be most optimal way to rewrite this iteration with java 8 stream().

```
for (name : names){
  if(name == a){
    doSomething();
    break;
  }
  if(name == b){
   doSomethingElse();
   break; 
 }
 if(name == c){
  doSomethingElseElse();
  break;
 }
}
```

Basically, iterating over the list with 3 conditions if any of them is satisfied want to break loop and in every condition want to call different method.

Comment: This code will not do what you think it does; use `equals` to compare strings instead of `==`. See: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Your "basically" doesn't describe what you're doing, as you're *also* calling a different method for each of those three conditions. Why do you *want* to rewrite this to use `stream()`? It doesn't look like it fits very naturally.

Comment: I'm just wondering if it is possible to do it with stream() in single iteration.

Comment: Your code does not need iteration at all. Just use `contains`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The answer by Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41117159/1421925) is definitely the straightforward way of performing the search. However, I would like to propose a slightly different approach:

```
private static final Map<String, Runnable> stringToRunnable = new HashMap<>();

{
  stringToRunnable.put("a", this::doSomething);
  stringToRunnable.put("b", this::doSomethingElse);
  stringToRunnable.put("c", this::doSomethingElseElse);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> names = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "b", "a");
  names.stream()
      .filter(stringToRunnable::containsKey)
      .findFirst()
      .ifPresent(name -> stringToRunnable.get(name).run());
}

private void doSomethingElseElse() {
}

private void doSomethingElse() {
}

public void doSomething() {
}
```

The part that does the job is the code below, but I added it to a `main()` function assuming `a`, `b`, and `c` are strings. However, the idea would work with any datatype.

```
names.stream()
    .filter(stringToRunnable::containsKey)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(name -> stringToRunnable.get(name).run());
```

The idea is to keep a map of keys and [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)s. By having `Runnable` as value it is possible to define a void method reference without parameters. The stream first filters away all values not present in the map, then finds the first hit, and executes its method if found.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `anyMatch` to find the first element matching one of your conditions and terminate. Use side effects for calling the processing methods :

```
boolean found =
  names.stream()
       .anyMatch (name -> {
                  if (name.equals(a)) {
                    doSomething();
                    return true;
                  } else if (name.equals(b)) {
                    doSomethingElse ();
                    return true;
                  } else if (name.equals(c)) {
                    doSomethingElseElse ();
                    return true;
                  } else {
                    return false;
                  }
                }
              );
```

Pretty ugly, but does what you asked in a single iteration.

Answer (score -3):

```
Collection collection;
collection.forEach(name->{
    if(name.equals(a))){
       doSomething();

    }
    if(name.equals(b)){
        doSomethingElse();

    }
    if(name.equals(c)){
        doSomethingElseElse();

    }
});
```

Comment: I want the loop to brake if it enters in any of the if statements, because only single If could be possible true for every list.